# Is there a way for me to fetch all message history from Thumbtack's web site?

Tags: web-scraping, privacy-policy, data-collection

I own a pro account and have been delivering services for years now. I have thousands of messages about services I provided.

I would like to prepare a digital document of all the services I provided with details of the products, prices etc. For that, I need to collect all my message history where there are details of these services.

I would like to learn the best practice for fetching all my message history from Thumbtack.

I checked their web site and they do not provide an API for third parties to interact with their site.

I tried to mimic the request for login operation but I got an 422 response.

I checked the web site if there is an option to export messages but there is none.

Since I have thousands of messages, it is not feasible to write them down manually. I have read their terms but am unsure if they allow web scraping. Is my only hope to ask them if they would provide this for me or do I have any other options?

Open to any suggestions.